# Wide to long but where I want to use a prefix instead of a suffix

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with the following data, where ultimately instead of having old/new in the variable name, I would like to compare old x with new x, old y with new y, etc., where the oldness and newness is contained in the "age" variable.

```
np.random.seed(5)
dat = []

for r in range(100):
  v = np.random.rand(6)
  rec = {
    "i": r,
    "old_x": v[0],
    "old_y": v[1],
    "old_z": v[2],
    "new_x": v[3],
    "new_y": v[4],
    "new_z": v[5],
  }
  dat.append(rec)

df = pd.DataFrame(dat)

>>> df
     i     old_x     old_y     old_z     new_x     new_y     new_z
0    0  0.110519  0.096792  0.980107  0.156369  0.540795  0.358307
1    1  0.292648  0.623699  0.376485  0.271227  0.931222  0.391800
2    2  0.872280  0.412259  0.831854  0.417520  0.874671  0.267805
3    3  0.497580  0.342821  0.338618  0.447617  0.618905  0.630221
4    4  0.611636  0.413489  0.302103  0.855590  0.061317  0.155975
..  ..       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
95  95  0.798706  0.085928  0.215995  0.819614  0.074777  0.876801
96  96  0.997671  0.344107  0.335971  0.199516  0.238919  0.852654
97  97  0.437936  0.924561  0.668733  0.148862  0.166350  0.861785
98  98  0.822570  0.426939  0.935153  0.771598  0.555669  0.639590
99  99  0.849823  0.960070  0.437960  0.675045  0.745331  0.428660

[100 rows x 7 columns]
```

I'd like to reshape this into a dataframe given by `columns = ["age", "x", "y", "z"]` where age takes values `["old", "new"]`.

Here's what I tried:

```
>>> pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['old',"new"], i='i', j='age', sep='_', suffix=r'\w+')
             old       new
i  age                    
0  x    0.110519  0.156369
1  x    0.292648  0.271227
2  x    0.872280  0.417520
3  x    0.497580  0.447617
4  x    0.611636  0.855590
...          ...       ...
95 z    0.215995  0.876801
96 z    0.335971  0.852654
97 z    0.668733  0.861785
98 z    0.935153  0.639590
99 z    0.437960  0.428660

[300 rows x 2 columns]
```

You can see this is kind of the reverse of what I'm looking for.  This also didn't work:

```
df.pivot_table(values=["x", "y", "z"], index=[i], columns='age')

KeyError: 'x'
```

What I'm looking for is more like:

```
>>> df
     i         x         y         z  age
0    0  0.110519  0.096792  0.980107  old  
     0  0.156369  0.540795  0.358307  new
1    1  0.292648  0.623699  0.376485  old
     1  0.271227  0.931222  0.391800  new
2    2  0.872280  0.412259  0.831854  old  
     2  0.417520  0.874671  0.267805  new
```

I'm fine if "old" and "new" are bools rather than strings.

Comment: can you create a small sample, with your expected output. and if the data is randomised, then use `np.random.seed` to ensure the randomisation is *constant*

Comment: Thanks, @sammywemmy added

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
df.set_index(['i'], inplace=True)
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_').map(tuple)  
df.stack(level=0).rename_axis(('i', 'age')).reset_index()

#      i  age         x         y         z
#0     0  new  0.918611  0.488411  0.611744
#1     0  old  0.221993  0.870732  0.206719
#2     1  new  0.187721  0.080741  0.738440
#3     1  old  0.765908  0.518418  0.296801
#4     2  new  0.274086  0.414235  0.296080
#..   ..  ...       ...       ...       ...
#195  97  old  0.960385  0.784069  0.922694
#196  98  new  0.056743  0.165556  0.430358
#197  98  old  0.460486  0.734635  0.953751
#198  99  new  0.174529  0.041988  0.635096
#199  99  old  0.027449  0.359603  0.423178

#[200 rows x 5 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Method 1: using `columns.str.split` and `stack`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split("_", expand=True)
df = df.stack(level=0).reset_index(level=1).rename(columns={"level_1": "age"})
```

```
    age    x    y    z
0   new 0.92 0.49 0.61
0   old 0.22 0.87 0.21
1   new 0.19 0.08 0.74
1   old 0.77 0.52 0.30
2   new 0.27 0.41 0.30
..  ...  ...  ...  ...
97  old 0.96 0.78 0.92
98  new 0.06 0.17 0.43
98  old 0.46 0.73 0.95
99  new 0.17 0.04 0.64
99  old 0.03 0.36 0.42

[200 rows x 4 columns]
```

---

#### Method 2: `Melt` and `Pivot`

We can use `melt` then split your column names and pivot back again:

```
d = df.melt(id_vars="i", var_name="age")
d[["age", "columns"]] = d["age"].str.split("_", expand=True)
d = d.pivot_table(index=["i", "age"], columns="columns", values="value")

d = d.reset_index(level="age").rename_axis(columns=None)
```

```
    age    x    y    z
i                     
0   new 0.92 0.49 0.61
0   old 0.22 0.87 0.21
1   new 0.19 0.08 0.74
1   old 0.77 0.52 0.30
2   new 0.27 0.41 0.30
..  ...  ...  ...  ...
97  old 0.96 0.78 0.92
98  new 0.06 0.17 0.43
98  old 0.46 0.73 0.95
99  new 0.17 0.04 0.64
99  old 0.03 0.36 0.42

[200 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: I like the first method (I need to practice my "stack"-skills :) +1

Comment: Thanks @AndrejKesely I agree, stack can be really convenient in transforming data.

Comment: I agree, thats why method 1 is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html) to reshape the data:

```
df.pivot_longer(index = 'i', names_to=("age", ".value"), names_sep="_")
 
      i  age         x         y         z
0     0  old  0.221993  0.870732  0.206719
1     1  old  0.765908  0.518418  0.296801
2     2  old  0.441309  0.158310  0.879937
3     3  old  0.628788  0.579838  0.599929
4     4  old  0.327564  0.144164  0.165613
..   ..  ...       ...       ...       ...
195  95  new  0.779014  0.014644  0.692856
196  96  new  0.083641  0.930439  0.185207
197  97  new  0.626007  0.351780  0.699121
198  98  new  0.056743  0.165556  0.430358
199  99  new  0.174529  0.041988  0.635096

[200 rows x 5 columns]
```

In the code above, `names_to` determines how the new column names will be: you have `old_x`, `old_y`,... `age` will be paired with `old`, `new`, while `x`, `y`, `z` will be paired with `.value`. `.value` indicates to the function that `x`, `y` and `z` will remain as column names, while the others will be transformed into the `age` column.

You could also stick to pandas only and use [wide_to_long](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html); first reorder the columns:

```
new_df = df.rename(columns = lambda col: "_".join(col.split("_")[::-1]) 
                                         if "_" in col else col)

new_df
 
     i     x_old     y_old     z_old     x_new     y_new     z_new
0    0  0.221993  0.870732  0.206719  0.918611  0.488411  0.611744
1    1  0.765908  0.518418  0.296801  0.187721  0.080741  0.738440
2    2  0.441309  0.158310  0.879937  0.274086  0.414235  0.296080
3    3  0.628788  0.579838  0.599929  0.265819  0.284686  0.253588
4    4  0.327564  0.144164  0.165613  0.963931  0.960227  0.188415
..  ..       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
95  95  0.883177  0.936967  0.771458  0.779014  0.014644  0.692856
96  96  0.034320  0.754875  0.424930  0.083641  0.930439  0.185207
97  97  0.960385  0.784069  0.922694  0.626007  0.351780  0.699121
98  98  0.460486  0.734635  0.953751  0.056743  0.165556  0.430358
99  99  0.027449  0.359603  0.423178  0.174529  0.041988  0.635096
```

Let's reshape:

```
(pd.wide_to_long(new_df, 
                 stubnames = ['x', 'y', 'z'], 
                 i = 'i', 
                 j = 'age', 
                 sep = '_', 
                 suffix = '.+')
  .reset_index()
)

      i  age         x         y         z
0     0  old  0.221993  0.870732  0.206719
1     1  old  0.765908  0.518418  0.296801
2     2  old  0.441309  0.158310  0.879937
3     3  old  0.628788  0.579838  0.599929
4     4  old  0.327564  0.144164  0.165613
..   ..  ...       ...       ...       ...
195  95  new  0.779014  0.014644  0.692856
196  96  new  0.083641  0.930439  0.185207
197  97  new  0.626007  0.351780  0.699121
198  98  new  0.056743  0.165556  0.430358
199  99  new  0.174529  0.041988  0.635096

[200 rows x 5 columns]
```

[pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) is a wrapper around Pandas functions, and helps abstract the reshaping process while dealing with things like duplicated index; it is also efficient

Answer (score 1):

```
x = pd.concat(
    [
        df.filter(like="old")
        .rename(columns=lambda x: x.split("_")[1])
        .assign(age="old"),
        df.filter(like="new")
        .rename(columns=lambda x: x.split("_")[1])
        .assign(age="new"),
    ],
).sort_index(kind="mergesort")
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
           x         y         z  age
0   0.221993  0.870732  0.206719  old
0   0.918611  0.488411  0.611744  new
1   0.765908  0.518418  0.296801  old
1   0.187721  0.080741  0.738440  new
2   0.441309  0.158310  0.879937  old
2   0.274086  0.414235  0.296080  new
3   0.628788  0.579838  0.599929  old
3   0.265819  0.284686  0.253588  new
4   0.327564  0.144164  0.165613  old
4   0.963931  0.960227  0.188415  new
5   0.024307  0.204556  0.699844  old
5   0.779515  0.022933  0.577663  new
6   0.001642  0.515473  0.639795  old
6   0.985624  0.259098  0.802497  new
7   0.870483  0.922750  0.002214  old
7   0.469488  0.981469  0.398945  new
8   0.813732  0.546456  0.770854  old

...
```